# m2eclipse says "Missing artifact" but I can build from cmdline!

Tags: maven, dependencies, m2eclipse

I'm trying to use this Sonatype Eclipse plugin for the first time to handle an existing (huge) software that I can build with maven form the command line.

I have configured the plugin to use my maven 2.2.1 installation instead of the built-in Maven 3.

In Eclipse I have 25 projects (loaded through the root pom.xml) and 4 of them have compilation errors; the maven console contains a lot of lines like this one:

Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile

I have all the jars in my repository and the M2_REPO classpath variable correctly defined.  Why the plugin doesn't see all the jars?

The .classpath file of those projects simply references "MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER", there isn't a list of the jars.
The pom.xml in Eclipse shows an error on the first line for the missing jars but I can build from the command line!

Any idea?  I need help!  I will try to move to NetBeans if I don't solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround.  It is surely a bug in m2eclipse, however the problem disappeared when I added `quartz-1.6.0.pom` next to `quartz-1.6.0.jar` in `.m2\repository\opensymphony\quartz\1.6.0\`
The pom is not present at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/opensymphony/quartz/1.6.0/ but you can extract it from `quartz-1.6.0-bundle.jar` linket at http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/QUARTZ-482
It's a strange solution but it worked on the PCs of my collegues too.

Comment: I've checked into the local repository and found quartz-1.6.2.jar but without the pom, however, after doing what @Jurie said, it's resolved in my case.

Answer (score 12):

You may need to to tell Eclipse to force update:

```
Project -> Maven -> Update Maven Project
```

and then make sure you have selected:

```
Force Updates of Snapshots/Releases
```

this happens when mvn install copies some jar files into Maven repository and Eclipse had checked this repo BEFORE this jar has been copied there.

Answer (score 7):

If Dependency management is enabled when the above problems occur in Eclipse you can `Project > Maven > Disable Dependency Management and then \Project > Maven > Enable Dependency Management`. This normally remove any dependency errors in the pom.xml.

Also do as @Nishant indicated in his answer above after the above steps to complete the projects dependencies.

Comment: That option isn't there anymore (at least with my installation), but I was able to clear the message by moving the pom.xml into a project folder and then moving it back.

Comment: Do add Maven nature on older versions of Eclipse (e.g. Indigo) right click on Project > Configure > Convert to Maven project

Comment: What happens when you have an actual dependency issue?  Just because there is a quirk in the software, I don't recommend disabling the feature.  Take a look at the other answers first before resorting to this.

Answer (score 5):

`right click on your project > Maven > Update Dependencies`

then

`right click on your project > Maven > Update Project configuration`

Assuming you M2Eclipse plugin is installed correctly this should solve the issue. Also, check if there is an option `right click project > Maven > Enable dependency Management` select that.

Comment: Both update commands generate again that list of "Missing artifact" errors.  I have tried both my maven 2.2.1 installation and the built-in Maven 3.
Dependency management is enabled.
Is there any internal index that is not updated by those commands?
I have even tried to reinstall Eclipse Helios SR2 from scratch along with the plugin from Eclipse Marketplace: nothing changed.

Comment: This maybe caused by some fight between built-in Maven3 (m2eclipse) and command-line Maven2 as they share the same local repository `~/.m2/repository`. Some temporary solution may be to remove the local repository (or at least the problematic artifacts) and let Eclipse with the M2Eclipse plug-in to fetch the dependencies again. Or update command-line Maven2 to Maven3.

Answer (score 2):

Using Eclipse Kepler, the removing and re-adding of the maven nature fixed this same issue I was having.  What this process actually did was modify the .settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs file, changing the line

```
resolveWorkspaceProjects=false
```

to

```
resolveWorkspaceProjects=true
```

So you could probably make this change manually if you had to.

Comment: Changing this setting by hand finally fixed my problem. Oddly enough, clicking though GUI did not.

Comment: It was set to true but no luck!

Answer (score 2):

**Adding my 2c for future Googlers:**

Whenever this problem shows up, I delete the corresponding folder from the m2 repository (on a mac it's on `~/.m2/repository)` and build again from eclipse with `clean install`.

Works every single time.

Answer (score 1):

Close eclipse IDE and open it again, this issue should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add yet another possible resolution, if you have a multi-project build with interdependencies, if you have a repository defined in a child project pom to resolve a specific dependency that only that project depends on and it is relying on a partent project for it's other resolutions it fails to see those dependencies in the child project (even though it works from the command line).

Move the repo definition to the parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of jars in the build path suggests you haven't enabled Maven dependencies. Right-click on the project, select Maven, select "Enable Maven Dependency Management". This allows M2Eclipse to reference your POM.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other suggestions worked, but the following steps worked for me (SpringSource Tool Suite 2.6.1):

- Back up the contents of the local Maven repository
- Delete the repository
- Project > Maven > Update Dependencies
- Replace anything not available in a public repository from the backup

Answer (score 0):

If disabling and enabling project dependency management doesn't help (usualy it helps) you can modify .classpath file in your project and add a line:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
```

After eclipse restart dependencies should be added.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem happened to me. On the CLI clean install, then on eclipse delete the dependency, paste it again and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the artifacts except the jar in maven local repository

Answer (score 0):

Late answer: In my case I had multiple profiles in settings.xml. Building worked since the correct profile was selected in the Maven Build run config, but the editors showed errors because the profile was not selected via Project -> Maven -> Select Maven Profiles ...