# Eclipse Indigo + me2 project import: Unknown packaging / could not find artifact

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, jenkins

Note: I'm just getting started with Jenkins plugin development and have never used maven before.

I have successfully set up a [sample plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) with maven and the command
line. (HelloWorldBuilder is building and running correctly via `mvn
hpi:run`.)

I have then installed [eclipse (indigo)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor) and the [m2e plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) and tried to
import the maven project into eclipse. (Via Import > Existing Maven
Projects)

The project is imported, but it displays two errors:

@pom.xml, line 1 :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

> Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
>   org.jenkins- ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:1.72 or one of its dependencies
>   could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5
>   at specified path C:\Programme\Java\jre6/../lib/tools.jar

@pom.xml, line 12 :

```
<packaging>hpi</packaging>
```

> Project build error: Unknown packaging: hpi

Any ideas?

- I have already changed the m2e setting (Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations) for the maven installation to use my maven 2.1.1 that I use on the command line.
- I have also tried Right-Click-Project > Maven > Update-Dependencies... / Update-Project-Configuration / and Enable-Workspace-Resolution  (whatever these settings mean)
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5500534/321013) seems to describe a similar problem, but I have no clue whether it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your Eclipse installation runs under a Java JRE instead of a Java JDK, this is why the tools jar could not be found.

M2Eclipse normally warns the user about that fact at first startup.

The solution is to specify the jdk executable in the eclipse.ini file like shown below.

add:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/javaw.exe
```

before the line starting with -vmargs

Comment: Ah nice. The two errors are gone (replaced by other, but hey). Note that I already had added the JDK in the Eclipse preferences, but didn't think to check with which java the actual IDE was running.

Answer (score 0):

1) As Torsten said you need to use JDK, not JRE.
In Eclipse Window->Preferences

[Java / Installed JREs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Setting+up+Eclipse+to+build+Jenkins)

2) See also [Jenkins plug-in developing - Maven issue: Unknown packaging: hpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003368/jenkins-plug-in-developing-maven-issue-unknown-packaging-hpi)