# Failure to find org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:2.11 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Tags: maven, jenkins, plugins

I am trying to compile a maven project that is designed to work as a Jenkins plugin. When running the "mvn package" command, I get the error listed below. What can be done to resolve the problem?

TIA

Saw this:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api/3.5.0
and took out the part that had the Maven Plugin defined as a "parent" and instead made it a "dependency"

Then I started getting errors like: **"Unknown packaging: hpi @ line 12, column 13"**

I then saw the following:
[Jenkins plug-in developing - Maven issue: Unknown packaging: hpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003368/jenkins-plug-in-developing-maven-issue-unknown-packaging-hpi)
It said  => "Also, add the details to your .m2/settings.xml as shown at the top of this tutorial to allow the use of the short name "hpi"."

After changing settings.xml (according to the link) still kept getting "Unknown packaging..." error

I then went back to the original pom.xml file that came with the package.

**The pom.xml file is listed below:**

[image: POM FILE]

This time, after using it, it seemed as though any/all jar files associated with Jenkins were downloaded (which took some time). The "hpi" error was gone but was replaced with a new one

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running InjectedTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 3, Errors: 12, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 60.722 sec <<< FAILURE! - in InjectedTest
edu\utah\med\ped\WaveMakerDeployer\config.jelly(org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck)  Time elapsed: 0.338 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: <?jelly escape-by-default='true'?> is missing in file:/C:/WORK/Development/JENKINS/WaveMakerJenkinsDeployer/target/classes/edu/utah/med/ped/WaveMakerDeployer/config.jelly
        at org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck.runTest(JellyTestSuiteBuilder.java:108)

edu\utah\med\ped\WaveMakerDeployer\global.jelly(org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck)  Time elapsed: 0.086 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: <?jelly escape-by-default='true'?> is missing in file:/C:/WORK/Development/JENKINS/WaveMakerJenkinsDeployer/target/classes/edu/utah/med/ped/WaveMakerDeployer/global.jelly
        at org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck.runTest(JellyTestSuiteBuilder.java:108)

index.jelly(org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck)  Time elapsed: 0.019 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: <?jelly escape-by-default='true'?> is missing in file:/C:/WORK/Development/JENKINS/WaveMakerJenkinsDeployer/target/classes/index.jelly
        at org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck.runTest(JellyTestSuiteBuilder.java:108)

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method index.jelly(org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck) from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@450f78c9

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method edu\utah\med\ped\WaveMakerDeployer\config.jelly(org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck) from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@4877102b

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method edu\utah\med\ped\WaveMakerDeployer\global.jelly(org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck) from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@c69c38

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods


Results :

Failed tests:
  JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck.runTest:108 <?jelly escape-by-default='true'?> is missing in file:/C:/WORK/Development/JENKINS/WaveMakerJenkinsDeployer/target/classes/edu/utah/med/ped/WaveMakerDeployer/config.jelly
  JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck.runTest:108 <?jelly escape-by-default='true'?> is missing in file:/C:/WORK/Development/JENKINS/WaveMakerJenkinsDeployer/target/classes/edu/utah/med/ped/WaveMakerDeployer/global.jelly
  JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck.runTest:108 <?jelly escape-by-default='true'?> is missing in file:/C:/WORK/Development/JENKINS/WaveMakerJenkinsDeployer/target/classes/index.jelly
Tests in error:
org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)
  Run 1: Filter.initializationError ▒  No tests found matching Method index.jelly(org.j...
  Run 2: Filter.initializationError ▒  No tests found matching Method edu\utah\med\ped\...
  Run 3: Filter.initializationError ▒  No tests found matching Method edu\utah\med\ped\...
  Run 4: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
  Run 5: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
  Run 6: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
  Run 7: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
  Run 8: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
  Run 9: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
  Run 10: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
  Run 11: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
  Run 12: Filter.initializationError ▒  No runnable methods
```

**QUESTION: Where can one go from here? How important are these "default" injection tests**

TIA

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When developing a jenkins plugin, you need to configure maven to find libraries from repo.jenkins-ci.org. Here's a sample `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<settings>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.jenkins-ci.tools</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>

  <profiles>
    <!-- Give access to Jenkins plugins -->
    <profile>
      <id>jenkins</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> <!-- change this to false, if you don't like to have it on per default -->
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
          <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
          <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
      <mirrorOf>m.g.o-public</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

This is from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial. Note that if you're using nexus there are nexus-specific alternate instructions that you can find over there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found an old thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003368/jenkins-plug-in-developing-maven-issue-unknown-packaging-hpi  that pretty much said the same thing you did. I made a change to the settings.xml file accordingly. The .java source file seems to have compiled but now, it seems default injection tests are ran (even though no JUnit test procedures were created in the first place). How important are these default testing procedures? Would it still be OK to try to import this .hpi into Jenkins?

Comment: you can hose a jenkins instance with a plugin. you would probably be a good judge of how likely that is given your changes. you could always fire up a test jenkins instance--with docker perhaps--in order to ensure that your plugin doesn't set it on fire. :)

Comment: >> you can hose a jenkins instance with a plugin.

Comment: LOL - this is what I was thinking " you could always fire up a test jenkins instance--with docker perhaps--in order to ensure that your plugin doesn't set it on fire" How would one do this? What is "docker"?

Comment: Also, would you have any insight as to what this is: =>
edu\utah\med\ped\WaveMakerDeployer\config.jelly(org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck)  Time elapsed: 0.338 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: <?jelly escape-by-default='true'?> is missing in file:/C:/WORK/Development/JENKINS/WaveMakerJenkinsDeployer/target/classes/edu/utah/med/ped/WaveMakerDeployer/config.jelly
        at org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyCheck.runTest(JellyTestSuiteBuilder.java:108)

Comment: What is "jelly"?

Comment: docker is one of the biggest gamechangers in tech in the past decade. you should check it out! once you have docker installed (you can install it on pretty much any machine these days), you can fire up a fresh jenkins server with a one-liner. i have no idea what is causing that assertion error you pasted. jenkins uses jelly in composing user interfaces. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Basic+guide+to+Jelly+usage+in+Jenkins. you are all full of questions tonight! i am sleepy. i wish you a good night, sir!

Comment: Hey - I got it to compile - now need to test to see if it will work! I found this here : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jelly+and+XSS+prevention which said to put "<p>My name is ${it.fullName}</p>" at the top of each jelly file. I did that and ran maven once more. It had ZERO errors thereafter :-))) Now - just need to do the testing using "decoder" as you have mentioned. Last question tho: I created the .hpi file on a Windows system. Jenkins is on a Linux system. The .hpi should be good to go on Linux (even though it was created on Windows) - right? TIA

Comment: yeah, you're using java and java is awesome, so it should be fine cross-platform.

Comment: OK - good - thanks again! BTW, it is "docker" and not "decoder" - it was late last night and I was tired ...

Comment: np! yeah, i either understood "docker" or was too tired to notice. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

burnettk's answer, except I am using Gradle, so for me it is

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url('https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/')
    }
}
```

In the Maven configuration, the `<pluginRepositories>` subtree could be safely left out, I guess.